# How to get the microtime for nextday 7am

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a php process for every day at 7 am morning. For this am maintaining a db column for time , where i should update the corresponding microtime for next day.
am able to get the next day time by `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));` but i want tomorrow 7am corresponding time.

Can anybody help me how to get the corresponding time for next day 7 am so that i can update according the db column.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong tools for the job -- If you're trying to run a process at a given time every day, you should be using a `cron` job. This PHP solution sounds waaay overcomplex.

Comment: Why microtime? Is it really needed - or did you just mean unix timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put it in `strtotime()`:

```
$unix = strtotime('tomorrow 7am');//unix timestamp
```

Not sure why you'd need microtime for this?

Comment: I was thinking that but I wasn't sure it would actually work mixing 'tomorrow' with '7am' - nice.

Comment: @user2211050 If this has solved your problem, please make future visitors of the site aware of how it was solved, by clicking the tick under the vote arrows.

Comment: pretty sure today at midnight wouldnt mean tomorrow 7am but rather the following day after tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Use [mktime](http://php.net/mktime)

```
mktime($hour = 7, $minute = 0, $second = 0, $month = date('n'), $day = date('j') + 1))
```

This will give you timestamp (in seconds). If you really need microtime, multiply with 1000

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate and simple way to launch activities which are scheduled to be run every nth minute/hour by using Cron tabs in *nix machine.

`* 7 * * * /path/to/wget /path/to/php`

This would launch your PHP file every day @ 07:00 hours.

[More info on crontab](http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/)